# How to ask "Yes" or "No" using Golang

Tags: go, prompt

I'm using `promptUi` to create a select list. Now I want to prompt a "Yes" or "No" question after a selection:

```
bold := color.New(color.Bold).SprintFunc()
cellTemplate := &promptui.SelectTemplates{
    Label:    "{{ . }}",
    Active:   "\U000027A4 {{ .| bold }}",
    Inactive: "  {{ . | faint }}",
    Help:     util.Faint("[Use arrow keys]"),
}

cellPrompt := promptui.Select{
    Label:     util.YellowBold("?") + " Select an environment to be installed",
    Items:     getCreateEnvironmentList(),
    Templates: cellTemplate,
}
_, value, err := cellPrompt.Run()
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("Failed to select: %v", err)
}

switch value {
case constants.CELLERY_CREATE_LOCAL:
    {
        // Prompt yes or no
    }
case constants.CELLERY_CREATE_GCP:
    {
        // Prompt yes or no
    }
default:
    {
        Back()
    }
}
```

Is there a similar way to prompt that in an elegant way?

Comment: Do you mean a *confirm* prompt as the Github page of the lib has an example like this: https://github.com/manifoldco/promptui/blob/master/_examples/confirm/main.go

Comment: You can do it this way as well : https://gist.github.com/albrow/5882501

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this `func yesNo() bool`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/manifoldco/promptui"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(yesNo())
    fmt.Println(yesNo())

}
func yesNo() bool {
    prompt := promptui.Select{
        Label: "Select[Yes/No]",
        Items: []string{"Yes", "No"},
    }
    _, result, err := prompt.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Prompt failed %v\n", err)
    }
    return result == "Yes"
}
```

Output:

```
? Select[Yes/No]: 
  ▸ Yes
    No

✔ Yes
true
✔ No
false
```

Comment: This solution looks more cooler than what I had in mind. I was gonna ask the user to type "yes" or "no". Thanks for the idea!

Comment: promptui also supports yes or no questions using the normal Prompt instead of select. Just use IsConfirm: true